# How to calculate current flowing down a wire connecting charge to ground

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits

If charge Q is connected to ground through a wire, how would you calculate the current that flows as a function of time? No other information is given. I have not seen this type of problem in the texts I've used, so if anyone has the answer or can point to a reference that would be much appreciated!

Comment: I believe you need to know the resistance of the wire and the capacitance (with respect to ground) of the object holding the charge.

Comment: That you have not seen this problem is the consequence of the difficulty to calculate the current flow in such a long antenna problem. A vertical wire connected to ground and excited by a spark discharge from a charged conductor from the top would be an extremely hard problem combining an electromagnetic radiation problem with a non-linear gas discharge. It would not be fun to calculate, it would have different parametric regimes that one would have to analyze independently and there would be very little of "clean" teaching physics on this tough bone.

Answer (score 1):

There is a "capacitor" of some kind holding the charge at one end of the wire - with capacitance C.  It has initial charge Qo, and initial voltage Vo = Qo/C.  In this relatively simple case, a discharging capacitor has an exponential rate of discharge.  This website describes how to derive the exponential equation:
http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/capdis.html